# Is there really no way to implement confirm() and prompt() in a UWP WebView?

Tags: uwp

Has anyone gotten the most basic Javascript APIs like prompt() and confirm() to work in a UWP WebView? It's not surprising that they are not implemented, but is there really no way to support them in an app? If true, that's crazy...

Before you ask, we have too much HTML/Javascript already in place to rewrite it just for a new Windows app. It's silly to think we should have to do that, anyway.

The big problem is that there is no way to pause the Javascript thread while we wait for the user to read a dialog. Here are some of the things I have tried:

- ScriptNotify: This works fine for alert(), but we can't return a result, like confirm() does.
- AddWebAllowedObject: I tried implementing a native object and it was much closer. The Javascript called my native alert function and waited, but I can't get a dialog box to show before the native function returns a result. The UI just hangs. :(
- WebViewExecutionMode.SeparateThread: I finally tried running the WebView on a different thread. With that, the dialog actually came up, but then everything froze until the native function returned a result, again. A multi-threaded nightmare...

If this really is not possible, is Microsoft planning to add it any time soon? Android, macOS, and iOS web views all support these basic APIs; Piece of cake.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there really no way to implement confirm() and prompt() in a UWP WebView?

If you need to receive notifications and data in your app code sent from WebView-hosted script, you need to handle the `ScriptNotify` event.

> ScriptNotify: This works fine for alert(), but we can't return a result, like confirm() does.

As you know, the `confirm()` method maynot work well. But you could use [`MessageDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog) in UWP app as a workaround to take the same effects. For example:

HTML

```
<button id="btnConfirm" onclick="confirmBox('sure to delete?')">click me to confirm</button> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmBox(message) { 
        window.external.notify('typeConfirm:' + message); 
    }
</script>
```

C# Code behind

```
private async void WebView_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog dialog;
    string[] messageArray = e.Value.Split(':');
    string message;
    string type;
    if (messageArray.Length > 1)
    {
        message = messageArray[1];
        type = messageArray[0];
    }
    else
    {
        message = e.Value;
        type = "typeAlert";
    }
    dialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(message);
    Debug.WriteLine("type=" + type + " ,message=" + message);

    if (type.Equals("typeConfirm"))
    {
        dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Yes"));
        dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Cancel"));
        dialog.DefaultCommandIndex = 0;
        dialog.CancelCommandIndex = 1;
    }
    var result = await dialog.ShowAsync();
    if (result.Label.Equals("Yes"))
    {
        // do something you want, maybe invoke a script
        //await webView1.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { functionString });
    }
    else
    {
        // do something you want, maybe invoke a script
        //await webView1.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { functionString });
    }
}
```

> Before you ask, we have too much HTML/Javascript already in place to rewrite it just for a new Windows app

If you have concern for this to use above workaround, I'm afraid there is no other ways.

> If this really is not possible, is Microsoft planning to add it any time soon?

I'm sorry that we cannot tell whether a feature can be implemented in the future, but you can try to post your feature to [user voice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform). Anyway,using `confirm()` hosted in a `WebView` seems to be not recommended. You may consider other ways to transfer your HTML/JavaScript into UWP app if have conditions. Check this [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33206083/how-can-i-handle-confirm-dialog-in-webview-uwp-windows-10-app-c-sharp) for more details.

Comment: Then how does the Edge browser support this? Isn't it using the same EdgeHTML engine?

Comment: Really strange decision from Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Javascript / Typescript.
Will work in UWP apps, not in Edge/IE.

```
     async function confirm(title: string, message: string | null): Promise<boolean> {

        const UI = window['Windows'].UI;

        const dialog = new UI.Popups.MessageDialog(message, title);

        const yes = new UI.Popups.UICommand("Yes");
        yes.id = 0;
        const no = new UI.Popups.UICommand("No");
        yes.id = 1;
        dialog.commands.push(yes);
        dialog.commands.push(no);
        dialog.defaultCommandIndex = 0;
        dialog.cancelCommandIndex = 1;
        const result = await dialog.showAsync();
        return result.id === yes.id;
    }
```

Comment: I tried this approach too, but it still is not a replacement for the standard confirm function because it is async.